# NGINX. Скачивается PHP файл место запуска

Tags: php, linux, nginx

Настроил NGINX по этому ману https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-ubuntu-18-04-ru

Всё запустилось и все php файлы работают правильно.

Создал новую директорию /var/www/html/auth и добавил скрипт view.php. Сделал доступ по паролю.

И файл php скачивается место запуска.

```
server {
listen 80;
root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name 11.22.33.44;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

location /auth {
    auth_basic "Введите пароль";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpassw;
    try_files $uri/view.php =404;
}
```

}

Какие ещё надо добавить настройки для запуска скрипта view.php в директории /auth?

Answer (score -1):

для начала проверьте работает ли php-fpm

> sudo service php7.4-fpm status

проверить наличие самого сокета /var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock

и конечно перешерстить логи.

Comment: Все php скрипты по прямой ссылке работают нормальное, например site.ru/info/1.php. А вот через " location /auth " php скрипт скачивается, а не запускается.